# Parsing variables from config file in Bash

Tags: bash, parsing, variables, awk

Having the following content in a file:

```
VARIABLE1="Value1"
VARIABLE2="Value2"
VARIABLE3="Value3"
```

I need a script that outputs the following:

```
Content of VARIABLE1 is Value1
Content of VARIABLE2 is Value2
Content of VARIABLE3 is Value3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`awk -F\= '{gsub(/"/,"",$2);print "Content of " $1 " is " $2}' <filename>`

Just FYI, another pure bash solution

```
IFS="="
while read -r name value
do
echo "Content of $name is ${value//\"/}"
done < filename
```

Comment: You can also use `IFS="=" read -r name value` to handle the splitting (the `-r` has nothing to do with splitting, but is recommended unless you have a reason not to use it).

Comment: The awk and bash solutions will give different results if the value contains an equals sign.

Answer (score 68):

Since your config file is a valid shell script, you can source it into your current shell:

```
. config_file
echo "Content of VARIABLE1 is $VARIABLE1"
echo "Content of VARIABLE2 is $VARIABLE2"
echo "Content of VARIABLE3 is $VARIABLE3"
```

Slightly DRYer, but trickier

```
. config_file
for var in VARIABLE1 VARIABLE2 VARIABLE3; do
    echo "Content of $var is ${!var}"
done
```

Comment: @samson for one thing, it allows any and all malicious code to be injected.

Comment: Why would you worry about malicious code being injected from a config file? I suppose I could imagine such cases, but I needed to be able to do this from a file which only exists on my local machine, i.e. a list of user / password combinations...

Comment: You need to hard-code variable names in this answer. With the accepted answer, you do not, and that's what makes it much better.

Comment: @samson, I'd worry about that because the way small security breaches become large security breaches is attackers finding exploits they can leverage to increase their (often-initially-minimal) access. A configuration file with carelessly-assigned permissions is often just such an opportunity.

Comment: I would also prefer the accepted solution here because it works in more general cases and does it automatically independent of the variable names and amount

Comment: There's also a risk if a value is omitted from the config file. If a user is allowed to run the script but not modify the configuration, they may be able to circumvent the restriction by setting environment variables. You would need to protect the environment as an attack vector.

Answer (score 40):

If you need these...

### Features

- Single line and inline comments;
- Trimming spaces around `=` (ie `var = value` will not fail);
- Quoted string values;
- Understanding of DOS line endings;
- Keep safe, avoiding sourcing your config file.

### Code

```
shopt -s extglob
configfile="dos_or_unix" # set the actual path name of your (DOS or Unix) config file
tr -d '\r' < $configfile > $configfile.unix
while IFS='= ' read -r lhs rhs
do
    if [[ ! $lhs =~ ^\ *# && -n $lhs ]]; then
        rhs="${rhs%%\#*}"    # Del in line right comments
        rhs="${rhs%%*( )}"   # Del trailing spaces
        rhs="${rhs%\"*}"     # Del opening string quotes 
        rhs="${rhs#\"*}"     # Del closing string quotes 
        declare $lhs="$rhs"
    fi
done < $configfile.unix
```

### Comments

`tr -d '\r' ...` deletes DOS carriage return.
`! $lhs =~ ^\ *#` skips single line comments and `-n $lhs` skips empty lines.
Deleting trailing spaces with `${rhs%%*( )}` requires setting extended globbing with `shopt -s extglob`. 
(Apart using `sed`), you can avoid this, via the more complex:

```
rhs="${rhs%"${rhs##*[^ ]}"}"
```

### Test config file

```
## This is a comment 
var1=value1             # Right side comment 
var2 = value2           # Assignment with spaces 

## You can use blank lines 
var3= Unquoted String   # Outer spaces trimmed
var4= "My name is "     # Quote to avoid trimming 
var5= "\"Bob\""
```

### Test code

```
echo "Content of var1 is $var1"
echo "Content of var2 is $var2"
echo "Content of var3 is [$var3]"
echo "Content of var4 + var5 is: [$var4$var5]"
```

### Results

```
Content of var1 is value1
Content of var2 is value2
Content of var3 is [Unquoted String]
Content of var4 + var5 is: [My name is "Bob"]
```

Comment: Isn't rhs="${rhs%\"*}" for the closing quotes and rhs="${rhs#\"*}" for the opening quotes?

Comment: and another issue: when the value is "aaaa#AAAAA" script strips everything on the rhs from #

Comment: I can confirm this script fails if there's a `#` in the value.

Answer (score 9):

I do in this way

```
. $PATH_TO_FILE
```

Comment: similar to what Dave Kennedy said, this allows any and all malicious code to be injected

Comment: Only if someone change the original file in "$PATH_TO_FILE" on the other. If someone can do this, so, the system admin are sloppy.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '{print "Content of "$1" is "$3}' FS='[="]'
```

Result

```
Content of VARIABLE1 is Value1
Content of VARIABLE2 is Value2
Content of VARIABLE3 is Value3
```

Answer (score 0):

given a config file as follows :-

```
[a]
b=C
d=E;rm t1
[b]
g=h
```

the following one-liner will parse and hold the values :-

```
CFG=path-to-file; for ini in `awk '/^\[/' $CFG`;do unset ARHG;declare -A ARHG;while read A B;do ARHG[$A]=$B;echo "in section $ini, $A is equal to"  ${ARHG["$A"]};done < <(awk -F'=' '/\[/ {x=0} x==1 && $0~/=/ && NF==2 {print $1, $2} $0==INI {x=1}' INI="$ini" $CFG);declare -p ARHG;echo;done;printf "end loop\n\n";declare -p ARHG
```

Now, let's break that down

```
CFG=path-to-file;
for ini in `awk '/^\[/' $CFG` # finds the SECTIONS (aka "ini")
do 
  unset ARHG # resets ARHG 
  declare -A ARHG # declares an associative array
  while read A B
  do
    ARHG[$A]=$B
    echo "in section $ini, $A is equal to"  ${ARHG["$A"]}
  done < <(awk -F'=' '/\[/ {x=0} x==1 && $0~/=/ && NF==2 {print $1, $2} $0==INI {x=1}' INI="$ini" $CFG)
  # the awk splits the file into sections, 
  # and returns pairs of values separated by "="
  declare -p ARHG # displays the current contents of ARHG
  echo
done
printf "end loop\n\n"
declare -p ARHG
```

This allows us to save values, without using eval or backtick. 
To be "really clean", we could remove [:space:] at the start and end of line, ignore "^#" lines, and remove spaces around the "equals" sign.

Comment: of course, the use of "declare -A" requires a recent version of bash. 
For example, "GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)" does NOT include the "-A" parameter ...

Answer (score -1):

```
    # 
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # parse the ini like $0.$host_name.cnf and set the variables
    # cleans the unneeded during after run-time stuff. Note the MainSection
    # courtesy of : http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2007/11/08/parsing-ini-files-with-sed
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    doParseConfFile(){
        # set a default cnfiguration file
        cnf_file="$run_unit_bash_dir/$run_unit.cnf"

        # however if there is a host dependant cnf file override it
        test -f "$run_unit_bash_dir/$run_unit.$host_name.cnf" \
            && cnf_file="$run_unit_bash_dir/$run_unit.$host_name.cnf"

        # yet finally override if passed as argument to this function
        # if the the ini file is not passed define the default host independant ini file
        test -z "$1" || cnf_file=$1;shift 1;


        test -z "$2" || ini_section=$2;shift 1;
        doLog "DEBUG read configuration file : $cnf_file"
        doLog "INFO read [$ini_section] section from config file"

        # debug echo "@doParseConfFile cnf_file:: $cnf_file"
        # coud be later on parametrized ...
        test -z "$ini_section" && ini_section='MAIN_SETTINGS'

        doLog "DEBUG reading: the following configuration file"
        doLog "DEBUG ""$cnf_file"
        ( set -o posix ; set ) | sort >"$tmp_dir/vars.before"

        eval `sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*\=[[:space:]]*/=/g' \
            -e 's/#.*$//' \
            -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//' \
            -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' \
            -e "s/^\(.*\)=\([^\"']*\)$/\1=\"\2\"/" \
            < $cnf_file \
            | sed -n -e "/^\[$ini_section\]/,/^\s*\[/{/^[^#].*\=.*/p;}"`

        ( set -o posix ; set ) | sort >"$tmp_dir/vars.after"

        doLog "INFO added the following vars from section: [$ini_section]"
        cmd="$(comm -3 $tmp_dir/vars.before $tmp_dir/vars.after | perl -ne 's#\s+##g;print "\n $_ "' )"
        echo -e "$cmd"
        echo -e "$cmd" >> $log_file
        echo -e "\n\n"
        sleep 1; printf "\033[2J";printf "\033[0;0H" # and clear the screen
    }
    #eof func doParseConfFile
```