How do I set a bash variable using the output of grep
I have a text file hg.ini that contains lines that can be interpreted as bash variable assignments:
$ cat hg.ini
[hello goodbye]
x=hello.world
y=goodbye.cruel.cruel.world
z=I.dont.know.why.you.say.goodbye.I.say.hello

I would like to process that file to execute a bash command that sets a bash variable in this way:
x=hello.world echo $x
hello.world

I tried the following, but the $() idiom is interpreted as command rather than a variable assignment:
$(grep x= hg.ini|tr -d '\r\n') echo $x
x=hello.world: command not found

What can I use instead?

fwiw, x=123; x=hello.world echo $x will print 123 since the $x is expanded before the x=hello.world is executed; and if x is undefined then x=hello.world echo $x will print a blank line

For more general solutions, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571739/parsing-variables-from-config-file-in-bash

Does this answer your question? Parsing variables from config file in Bash

@Barmar, @pjh,
The referenced solution processes the whole file rather than specific lines chosen by grep.
The section header [hello goodbye] may execute as a bash command, but probably doesn't do what you want.

You can source the grep results like such:
$ typeset -p x
-bash: typeset: x: not found

$ source <(grep 'x=' hg.ini)

$ typeset -p x
declare -- x="hello.world"

As pointed out in comments you'll need to perform the assignment and follow-on echo as separate commands:
$ source <(grep 'x=' hg.ini); echo "$x"
hello.world


To clean up afterwards:
$ source <(grep 'x=' hg.ini); echo "$x" ; unset x

Use eval to execute the assignment in the file.
eval "$(grep '^x=' hg.ini)"


There's also declare which is less likely to do something bad with the string

Solutions that use eval are potentially dangerous because they can lead to unwanted code being run.  For instance, if you make a mistake editing hg.ini (or somebody else edits it with mischievous or malicious intent) and end up with these contents
[hello goodbye]
x=hello who
y=goodbye.cruel.cruel.world
z=I.dont.know.why.you.say.goodbye.I.say.hello

then simple code that uses eval may run the who command (generating information about the users logged in on the system) and not set x at all (because it is set only temporarily while the who command is running).
See Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead? and BashFAQ/048 (Eval command and security issues).
Using source is just as dangerous because source FILE is equivalent to eval "$(cat FILE)".  A simple solution that uses source may also run who and not set x.
This Shellcheck-clean Bash code will always set x and will never run any code contained in the hg.ini file:
#! /bin/bash -p

xass=$(grep x= hg.ini)
x=${xass#x=}

declare -p x

When run with the bad hg.ini file above this program outputs
declare -- x="hello who"

(showing that x is a scalar string variable containing the string hello who).

${xass#x=} expands to the value of xass (hopefully a line from hg.ini) with leading x= removed.  See Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?)).
declare -p x prints the value of x in an unambiguous way that may reveal invisible characters or unexpected variable properties.  echo "$x" is not a reliable way to print the value of a variable.  See Bash Pitfalls #14 (echo $foo).  printf '%s\n' "$x" is safe, but will not reveal invisible characters (e.g. trailing spaces) or variable properties.

